# Paypal Doesn't Show The Currency By Which We Checkout In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

Our site is having INR as the base currency & having Paypal Standard checkout.
Now what happens.....when we checkout & when our site redirects to paypal then in paypal page it is converted to USD. Now that is right because paypal doesn't support INR so INR gets converted to USD. That's right no issue.

But the issue is if in our website we switch currency (not base currency) to GBP then checkout, then when site is redirected to paypal then also it is converted to USD.....GBP is accepted in paypal right? Then also why it is converted to USD & not coming in GBP?

Can anyone help us with this?

Please note :
1) Our base currency is INR
2) We are using sandbox for testing

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You know that default Magento always checkout with base currency (your INR), not display currency (GBP)

In your case,you can set display currency (GBP) for each store view => so You can switch currency.

However, base currency (INR) is set up for the website. Therefore, in the frontend, you can see price with display currency (GBP), but when going to checkout, only base currency (INR) is used.

That is the reason why it is converted to USD, not GBP.

This is a very common issue in Magento and we can solve it with an extension like:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

It has a function that can help to set up base currency for each store view. Customers can checkout with currency of store view.

With your case, you can set up GBP for a store view . WHen customer buy product in this store view and go to checkout, they will checkout with GBP.